# c++ declare an array index as empty

Tags: c++, arrays, repeat

I have an array in which I have to ignore, delete all the numbers which are `repetitive`,

for example `1 2 4 3 3 0 1 2 0`

What I did is I checked the numbers and tried stuff like `\0` and `NULL` but both of them give the value of 0 so it's not a solution. So is there a way to make an index empty or just to ignore it? The numbers must be random so I can't declare something like

```
array[i]=123;
if(array[i]==123) dont_print_out();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your array is a plain C++ array, you have no method to "remove" items.
You only solution is to shift the remaining items to the left.

If your array is a `std::vector`, you can use the `erase` function. However, due to the structure of the underlying data in a vector, you do basically the same as before: it is inefficient.

If you want efficient removal of items randomly located in your sequence, consider using another kind of container, like a `std::list`.

Last, to achieve your goal, take a look at `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`. These containers ensure that your items are unique.

Comment: 1. Using `std::list` to support random removal is almost always a mistake. You lose more in traversing the list to find the duplicates than you gain in the removal itself being fast. 2. A vector with `std::unique` will usually be faster than `std::set` or even `std::unordered_set`. 3. You can erase from a vector efficiently as long as you don't care about maintaining the original order.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: 3. OK, if you move the end item to the _hole_ created by the removal, correct ?

Comment: You normally want to swap the item to be removed to the end. With `int` copying will be fine, but with something like `std::string` or `std::vector`, swap will typically be faster (and it would be quite unusual for it to be much, if any, slower).

Answer (score 2):

1. Use an `std::vector` instead of an array, so you can erase items<sup>1</sup>.
2. If you don't need to maintain the original order, it's probably easiest to sort, then use `std::unique` to eliminate the duplicates.

Code could look something like this:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;

srand(time(NULL));

std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(numbers), 10, rand);
std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
std::copy(numbers.begin(), std::unique(numbers.begin(), numbers.end()), 
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t"));

 // Or, as @Chris pointed out:
 std::unique_copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t"));
```

Note that since `std::unique` returns an iterator to the end of the range of unique numbers, we don't actually need to erase the others at all -- we can just use that as the end of the range we display.

Also note that as I've generated the numbers here, it would actually be pretty unusual to remove anything -- given the range of numbers produced by a typical implementation of `rand()`, it would be fairly unusual to see it produce any duplicates in only 10 iterations.

If you do need to maintain the original order, you have a couple of choices. One is to insert each item in a `std::set` (or `std::unordered_set`) as you print it out, and only print it out of inserting in the set was successful (i.e., it wasn't previously present).

---

<sub>1. Though that's only one of *many* reasons to prefer `std::vector` over an array.</sub>

Comment: Don't forget about [`std::unique_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy) :)